# Add a Dashboard to a Visualforce Page

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to create a public Visualforce page that contains a dashboard.
I have tried the iframe method but it upsets the companies CSP. Surveys__c is the object.

Running this code gives me a completely blank page. It is not pulling anything from the dashboard.

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" standardController="Surveys__c">

<dashboard dashboardId="01ZU0000000kWl3MAE" 
      showTitle="true" 
      />

</apex:page>
```

I would like to have a publicly accessible visual force page that displays the interactive data

Answer (score 0):

To show your dashboard into visualforce page You can use  Component.
 You will first need to add report and add chart in report to how it on a Visualforce page.Helpful link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.enus.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm
  https://automationchampion.com/tag/analyticsreportchart/

You can even customize dynamic dashboard by writing apex class and make use of different Charts of Visual force 
 Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting.htm
  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm"